# Java Cant download file from FtpClient when file has Japanese characters

Tags: java, utf-8, ftp, ftp-client

i have successfully created a connection to ftp server
and I'm trying to download multiple files with * wildcard

while working without `setControlEncoding("UTF-8");`  i don't get the real Japanese characters - i get some weird ASCII letters - adding the Encoding solved that issue .

```
        client.connect(ftpDetails.host, ftpDetails.port);
        client.setBufferSize(1024 * 1024);
        client.login(ftpDetails.username, ftpDetails.getSensitiveData());
        client.setControlEncoding("UTF-8");
///more code
```

But download this file is not available with this option  :

```
 InputStream stream =  FTPClient.retrieveFileStream(file.getName());
```

while during debug i see that the FTPFile exist - i cant download it with `FTPClient.retrieveFileStream`
Because the stream get null value

i assume my problem relates to the fact i have Jap characters - while file with english characters work as expected .

[image]

why do i get null and not able to download this file ?
has anyone been able to solved it ?